# Doctrine 2, how to order the joined records:

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to get all images of a person and order by sequentally. I have this:

person entity:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->leftJoin('p.personImages','c')
    ->orderBy('c.sequence', 'asc')
    ->getQuery() 
    ->getResult();
```

orderBy() has no effect, not even asc|desc. But if I misstype this field, it dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youve not 'selected' anything from the right hand table.  Because of this `c.sequence` will be null.

try this:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p')
    ->leftJoin('p.personImages','c')
    ->addSelect('c')
    ->orderBy('c.sequence', 'asc')
    ->getQuery() 
    ->getResult();
```